# SimpleCursorAdapter weird error

Tags: android

So my code is:

```
private class getRankedTeamsTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray> {
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
            // it is executed on Background thread
            return params[0].getRankedTeams();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {

            try {
                JSONObject json = null;
                if (jsonArray != null) {
                    json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    String[] columns = new String[6];

                    for(int i = 0; i<json.length(); i++){
                        columns[i] = json.names().getString(i);
                    }

                    MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(columns);

                    startManagingCursor(matrixCursor);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[] {jo.getString("teamName"), jo.getString("loses"), jo.getString("points"),
                                jo.getString("ranking"), jo.getString("wins")});
                    };

                    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
                            {R.id.teamNameLV, R.id.losesLV, R.id.pointsLV, R.id.rankLV, R.id.winsLV};

                    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter
                            = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                            this,
                            R.layout.custom_ranking,
                            matrixCursor,
                            columns,
                            toViewIDs
                    );

                    rankingList.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The code gets data from the database and I am trying to add the data to a custom dynamic `ListView` but I am getting some weird error that don't let the application run. Can someone help me? I saw lots of posts and tutorials about this and I only found this way, but I get error and they don't.

error:

```
Error:(92, 31) error: no suitable constructor found for SimpleCursorAdapter(RankingActivity.getRankedTeamsTask,int,MatrixCursor,String[],int[])
constructor SimpleCursorAdapter.SimpleCursorAdapter(Context,int,Cursor,String[],int[],int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor SimpleCursorAdapter.SimpleCursorAdapter(Context,int,Cursor,String[],int[]) is not applicable
(actual argument RankingActivity.getRankedTeamsTask cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
```

Comment: post this error from logcat

Comment: @nikis done, hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `this` in the `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor, you are referencing enclosing class, which is `getRankedTeamsTask`:

```
 SimpleCursorAdapter adapter
     = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
         this,
         R.layout.custom_ranking,
         matrixCursor,
         columns,
         toViewIDs
     );
```

However, the first argument should be a `Context` instance, which is your activity, so you should replace it with the following:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter
    = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        RankingActivity.this,
        R.layout.custom_ranking,
        matrixCursor,
        columns,
        toViewIDs
    );
```

Please note, that constructor you are [trying](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[]%29) to use is deprecated per docs, you should use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[],%20int%29) one instead.